# JDBC ResultSet with MySQL ignores ResultSet type

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to process large amount of data in Java application. Data is stored in MySQL database and I am using jdbc connector 8.0.11.

My problem is that I need to access each record multiple times and executing query again takes too much time. Using `ResultSet.absolute(1)` throws an exception explaining that cursor is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY.

As described [here](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/how-to-use-scrollable-result-sets-with-jdbc), a statement should be created with parameters `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` and `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY` parameter in order to obtain a result set with ability to scroll.

But my created `ResultSet` is always `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, ignoring any parameters provided in create statement method.

In official [MySQL site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/) I did not found any explanation nor information if this feature is supported.

For test case, I wrote this code to check if some other combination would affect `ResultSet` type and always got `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

```
Connection conn = Database.getConnection();
    Statement st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    if(st.getResultSetType() == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) {
        System.out.println("Should be scroll sensitive, is forward only");
    }
    st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    if(st.getResultSetType() == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) {
        System.out.println("Should be scroll insensitive, is forward only");
    }
    st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    if(st.getResultSetType() == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) {
        System.out.println("Should be scroll insensitive, is forward only");
    }
    st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    if(st.getResultSetType() == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) {
        System.out.println("Should be scroll sensitive, is forward only");
    }
    st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    if(st.getResultSetType() == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) {
        System.out.println("Should be scroll sensitive, is forward only");
    }
    st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
    if(st.getResultSetType() == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) {
        System.out.println("Should be scroll insensitive, is forward only");
    }
    st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
    if(st.getResultSetType() == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) {
        System.out.println("Should be scroll insensitive, is forward only");
    }
    st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
    if(st.getResultSetType() == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) {
        System.out.println("Should be scroll sensitive, is forward only");
    }       
    st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
    if(st.getResultSetType() == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) {
        System.out.println("Should be scroll sensitive, is forward only");
    }
```

Here is a code fragment explaining how I create the database connection:

```
private static final String driverName = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";

    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver dr = (com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver) Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();

    MysqlDataSource src = new MysqlDataSource();
    src.setUseCursorFetch(true);        
    src.setServerName("localhost");     
    src.setPort(port);
    src.setDatabaseName("dbname");
    src.setUseSSL(false);
    src.setUser(dbUser);
    src.setPassword(dbPass);
    src.setServerTimezone("GMT+2");
    conn = src.getConnection(dbUser, dbPass);
```

So I would like to ask:

1. Why is my `ResultSet` always `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`?
2. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Comment: JDBC drivers are allowed to downgrade the result set type if they can't fulfill the request. However I was under the impression that MySQL Connector/J did support (or at least simulated) scrollable cursors. I wonder if they changed that in version 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JDBC `ResultSet` is semantically similar to a *database cursor* but not all database systems, including MySQL, support cursors (see below). If `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` or `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` are implemented this usually means that the JDBC driver targets a database supporting scrollable cursors. Of course, a JDBC driver can still be written to emulate this behaviour by caching the result set, but most drivers don't do this.

From MySQL documentation ( (src: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html)

> MySQL does not support SQL cursors, and the JDBC driver does not
>   emulate them, so setCursorName() has no effect.

New versions of MySQL do partially support cursors ( http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/ ) but they're still not scrollable.

So, to do what you want, simply cache the result set (e.g. store it in a hash map or some other container) and retrieve a particular record when you need it.